# Configure Zend Framework to ignore other directories and work in a subdirectory?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have a default Zend Framework application installed under `/var/www/html/zend_example`. The public directory is: `/var/www/html/zend_example/public`.

I also have other non-zend sites in `/var/www/html`. For example, `/var/www/html/other_site`.

How can I configure the ZF site to work under `http://MYDOMAIN/zend_example` while simultaneously allowing `http://MYDOMAIN/other_site` to work?

Here is my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zend_example/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /var/www/html/zend_example/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html/zend_example/public`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I just want to get a development ZF site up and running, while also having other sites available (under the same base URL).

Right now, all requests redirect (or rewrite?) to the base URL (http://MYDOMAIN).

Thanks!

**Edit #1**

I edited the vhost for both `zend_example` and `other_site` so that each `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html`, rather than the subdirectories for each site. This made it possible to access both sites in their respective URLs - other_site: `http://MYDOMAIN/other_site` and zend_example: `http://MYDOMAIN/zend_example/public`. Now, I believe there is a problem with the `.htaccess` file that is in the `/var/www/html/zend_example/public` directory. I cannot access default "Zend" URLs such as `http://MYDOMAIN/zend_example/public/index/index` which should point to the IndexController. Instead I receive a `404` error.

**Edit #2**

If I disable all vhosts except for the `zend_example` one, and the zend_example vhost has `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` set, then I am able to run the Zend site under `http://MYDOMAIN/zend_example/public`, including specific default Zend routes, such as `http://MYDOMAIN/zend_example/public/index/index`. This breaks when I enable another vhost, although I am still able to access the main index page for Zend at `http://MYDOMAIN/zend_example/public`.

**Edit #3**

I ended up toying with this for hours. It seems that there is some unique configuration that needs to be done since my server is **centos 6.0**. I ended up setting up a Debian 6.0 server and was able to get my virtual hosts setup correctly, including the Zend site! I'd still like to come back and solve the issue on centos, though.

Comment: That setup looks about right to me. Is it not working? The only thing I would add, if you haven't already is a VHost for the other_site

Comment: @vascowhite The Zend site is working, per se, except that it only works at `http://MYDOMAIN/`, not `http://MYDOMAIN/zend_example`. It also prevents URLS such as `http://MYDOMAN/other_site/` from being accessed (it just throughs a Zend application error).

Comment: If this works on Debian and not Centos, the issue may be with the ownership/permissions of certain files or directories. I've encountered this before when trying to set up ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the `ServerName` option in your vhost. Also you may encounter some difficulties if you don't allow `followSymlinks` in your directory declaration, try something like:

```
//the ServerName is the name that would follow http:// (http://zend.example/module/controller/action)

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zend_example/public
    ServerName zend.example
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /var/www/html/zend_example/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not a *nix user so I'm not sure if you have change anything that resembles a windows hosts file or not, but it might pay to investigate. (it looks like you will have to edit the hosts file, it should be at `/etc/hosts` add a line like `127.0.0.1 zend.example` where zend.example = ServerName from your vhost)

P.S. you'll probably have to make a vhost (as the first one in the list if all of your vhost are in one file) for localhost if you need localhost available. I know I have to do this on windows.

Comment: The ServerName is part of some confusion for me. I am working on a remote server that I have not connected with a domain name, so I just access it by the IP. It has been my understanding that, if I setup a localhost vhost and a ServerName for my Zend app, it will still have to be accessed via the IP (not the server name). Does that make sense?

Comment: I added the `FollowSymlinks` rule that you suggested and I created a vhost for other_site. I checked `/etc/hosts` and it already had a localhost line in it. I'm looking through `httpd.conf` now for other ideas. Perhaps it is helpful to note that whichever vhost include is listed first in `httpd.conf`, then the first one appears at `http://MYDOMAIN/` and the second one can't be accessed. It's like the `DocumentRoot` is being ignored.

Comment: The fact that the site is remote, makes some difference. Now you need a proper vhost and a way to process a dns entry. If the remote is on the local network you can use the hosts file on each client machine to route to the sites (or setup a dns server on the server machine), if it's not on the local network then you're dealing with dns on the open internet. I've had any number of problems trying to access ZF sites by ip, there's a trick to it that I don't know.